# get the sum after the $unwind and $lookup returns 0

Tags: database, mongodb, nosql

Player collection:

```
{ "_id" : 1, "Name" : "John Aims", "Gender" : "M", "DoB" : ISODate("1990-01-01T00:00:00Z"), "Nationality" : "USA", "Hand" : "R", "YearTurnedPro" : 2010, "Tournament" : [ { "tournamentID" : 1, "TournamentYear" : 2016 }, { "tournamentID" : 2, "TournamentYear" : 2019 }, { "tournamentID" : 3, "TournamentYear" : 2021 } ] }
{ "_id" : 2, "Name" : "George Brown", "Gender" : "M", "DoB" : ISODate("1997-03-04T00:00:00Z"), "Nationality" : "GB", "Hand" : "L", "YearTurnedPro" : 2013, "Tournament" : [ { "tournamentID" : 2, "TournamentYear" : 2016 }, { "tournamentID" : 5, "TournamentYear" : 2019 } ] }
```

Tournament collection:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("626c18a3d880647a888888ff"), "TournamentID" : 1, "TournamentCode" : "GS1", "Position" : 8, "PrizeMoney" : 125000, "RankingPoints" : 250 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("626c18c2d880647a888888ff"), "TournamentID" : 2, "TournamentCode" : "GS1", "Position" : 4, "PrizeMoney" : 250000, "RankingPoints" : 500 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("626c18ddd880647a888888ff"), "TournamentID" : 3, "TournamentCode" : "GS1", "Position" : 1, "PrizeMoney" : 1000000, "RankingPoints" : 2000 }
```

1st Question:

Hello, I want to get the sum of ranking points of each player.

I have tried:

```
db.Player.aggregate([
  {"$unwind" : "$Tournament"}, 
{"$lookup":
{"from":"Tournament",
"localField":"Tournament.tournamentID",
"foreignField":"TournamentID",
"as":"Tennis-player"}},
  { "$group": {
    "_id": { Name:"$Name" },
    "total_qty": { "$sum": "$Tennis-player.PrizeMoney" }
  }}
])
```

But I get for every played the sum is 0.

I can show it on playground as it is using more than 1 collection.

2nd question:

Would it be better to create only 1 collections with all the data?

Answer (score 0):

1. `$unwind`
2. `$lookup`
3. `$set` - As from stage 2 `Tennis-player` returns an array with guarantee only 1 document in array. Use `$first` to get the first document in `Tennis-player` array field to become a document field.
4. `$group`

```
db.Player.aggregate([
  {
    "$unwind": "$Tournament"
  },
  {
    "$lookup": {
      "from": "Tournament",
      "localField": "Tournament.tournamentID",
      "foreignField": "TournamentID",
      "as": "Tennis-player"
    }
  },
  {
    $set: {
      "Tennis-player": {
        "$first": "$Tennis-player"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": {
        Name: "$Name"
      },
      "total_qty": {
        "$sum": "$Tennis-player.PrizeMoney"
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Sample Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/CQ48hMQI3mV)

---

Alternative:

1. `$lookup` - [Work `$lookup` with an Array](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/#use--lookup-with-an-array)
2. `$project` - Decorate output documents. Create `total_qty` field and use `$reduce` to perform sum operation of `Tennic-player.PrizeMoney`.

```
db.Player.aggregate([
  {
    "$lookup": {
      "from": "Tournament",
      "localField": "Tournament.tournamentID",
      "foreignField": "TournamentID",
      "as": "Tennis-player"
    }
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      "_id": {
        Name: "$Name"
      },
      "total_qty": {
        "$reduce": {
          "input": "$Tennis-player",
          "initialValue": 0,
          "in": {
            $sum: [
              "$$value",
              "$$this.PrizeMoney"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Sample Mongo Playground (Alternative)](https://mongoplayground.net/p/jgQE-cGymrF)